# Set text to a textView

Tags: android, textview

I want to set text to my textView1 but i cant because my app crashes! What can i do?
Please help!!! :(

```
public class settext extends Activity
{

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
  {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
text.setText("how to set Text");





}



}
```

When i start the application nothing appears and it crashes all the time i start it....
Does anyone know where i can find a way to read about programming in a site??

Comment: you have to java class file in your android mainfest with the given answer below.

Comment: without the setContentView they dont find your TextView textView1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you need to add a layout (View) in which textView1 would be there 
For example try this :

```
setContentView(R.layout.x1);
```

so your code would be like that

```
public class settext extends Activity
{

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
  {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.x1);

TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
text.setText("how to set Text");





}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `setContentView(your_layout)` before you can call

```
TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `setContentView`  with the `layout` which contains `textview1` i.e You need to define the `layout` in your `Activity`

Answer (score 1):

Your app is getting crash because your class does not have a reference of your activity layout. You must set layout.

```
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
        {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //Set setContentView in your code for example //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    //activity_main is my layout in projectfolder> res> layout> activity_main.xml 
    // so put reference of your layout in it.

        setContentView(R.layout.<yourLayout>);     
        TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        text.setText("how to set Text");
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi, you have to use

> setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);

try this

Answer (score 1):

Your app will really crash because you didn't put the setContentView() code in your code:

try this one:

```
public class settext extends Activity {

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.your_layout); //PUT THIS ON YOUR CODE

        TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        text.setText("how to set Text");

    }
}
```